# HTTP interceptor: Using url params instead of header for token based auth

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I have the following code for token based authentication with my backend api in AngularJS:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This sets the "Authorization" header to my token.

How do I have to modify my code to use an URL parameter (named "access_token") instead of an header?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the argument **params – {Object.}** of **config** object:

`params – {Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified.

[AngularJS reference guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                //config.headers = config.headers || {};
                 config.params = config.params || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                   config.params.access_token = $localStorage.token;                        
                   //config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. However it has some "side-effects". Using this solution leads to some problems with my rootscope (I set $rootScope.msg = Object ... However with your solution in use I can not output $rootScope.msg.message in my html file. Without your solution this works fine).